# How do I make a constructor have accessible members when its called as an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I can do this in JavaScript:

```
var output = String(result);
```

And I can do this with the same object that is referenced using `String`:

```
var character = String.fromCharCode(10);
```

`String` can be used as a function to construct an object *and* members can be called on it without using it as a constructor. How do I make an object usable in both these ways? What is this called?

Comment: what do u mean? like concat string with characters?

Comment: are you talking about multiple constructors? For example, you have a class. Based on how you create the instance of your class, you wanna do something in constructor. Is it what you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about class methods.

```
function Foo() {
  this.bar = 3
}

Foo.baz = function() {
  console.log('hi');
}
```

or in ES 2015

```
class Foo {
  static baz () {
    console.log('hi');
  }
}
```

### Response to the comments

You *can* define a static method in the constructor function because the constructor function is necessarily in scope:

```
function Foo() {
  Foo.method = function () {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

There are a couple of problems with this approach though:

```
Foo.method('stringy string'); // TypeError: cannot read property 'method' of undefined
```

Because the static method is defined in the constructor, it won't be there until the constructor function runs at least once:

```
const foo = new Foo();
Foo.method('stringy string'); // now we're good
```

which leads to another problem, now we're wastefully reassigning that method every time the constructor runs. You can avoid that with a conditional check:

```
function Foo() {
  if (!Foo.method) Foo.method = function....
}
```

But that's a lot of weird stuff just to avoid defining the class method after the constructor, and it still doesn't solve the first problem.

Comment: Can this be achieved using the older and more common constructor function way instead of using the special class syntax?

Comment: And without defining these static methods outside of the constructor body?

Comment: @Melab answer to your first comment is yes: I included both in my answer. The first example I gave is with the old-style constructor function. Answer to your second is *technically* yes, but that's a *terrible* idea: it means it wouldn't be defined until you instantiated an instance of the class and that it would be re-assigned with a new function *every time* you instantiate the class. Don't mess around with the class itself in the constructor function or get confused about the difference between the *class* and an *instance* of the class.

Comment: No, I mean using a constructor function and defining static methods *inside* the constructor function. My two two questions were conjunctive.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class with static methods:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    length() {
        return this.bar.length;
    }

    static fromThing(thing) {
        return new Foo(thing.bar);
    }
}
```

Foo.fromThing() is analogous to String.fromCharCode()

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
function MyClass () {
  this.val = 1;
}

MyClass.staticMethod = function () {/* code here */};
```